# No sound through headphones

Tags: 12.04, sound, alsa, headphones

I'm using Elementary OS Luna, which is based on Ubuntu 12.04. The sound was working fine, but after a restart, I could hear only through the speakers on my laptop and there is no audio when I plug-in my headphones.

I tried a lot of solution on the Internet, nothing seems to work. So I am posting it here.

If you guys need any further information I will be happy provide.

```
$ sudo aplay -l

[sudo] password for gowtham: 
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****

card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: ALC271X Analog [ALC271X Analog]

  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]

  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Do you have dell laptop ?

Comment: No it is an Acer 4739z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ubuntu there is such tool as alsamixer. Check if you have that in your distro. If you do, see if below the headphones bar there is two M letters , MM. That would mean headphones are muted. pressing m unmutes them. Check if that works. Alternatively, this could be a hardware issue, in which case i'd suggest usb headphones or bluetooth

Comment: Thanks for the response. I checked it out. The headphones bar was in MM. So I unmuted it (00). But I still don't seem to get the sound. I also restarted the machine after the change in Alsamixer. The headphones bar seem to be unmuted, but still no sound from headphones. I checked the earphones with my phone and it works alright. Do you need any other information?

Comment: Hmm, not sure. There's couple other softwares you could try, like PulseAudio manager or Pulse audio preferences. As for hardware part, besides headphones themselves it could be the headphones' socket, which is why i mentioned usb or bluetooth headphones. Sound card clearly works, because you have sound from speakers and we can eliminate the driver portion. So i'd say something with the settings or the headphones socket. Try making live cd of ubuntu or any other distro for that matter, and in live session test the headphones. If still doesn't work - most likely it's the sockets

Comment: I made a LiveUSB of Ubuntu as you suggested. The headphones worked fine in the live session. I logged back in to Elementary and installed PulseAudio manager and fooled around with it for a while and the headphones started working after a restart. I'm not sure what did the trick, but the issue is fixed now. Thanks a lot of the help and detailed answers. Have a good one!